# Use assetic output in config.yml

Tags: symfony, tinymce, assetic

I'm using assetic in a Symfony 2.4 project to generate and compress my CSS.
I'm also using some bundles that need a CSS in their configuration, like *content_css* parameter of [stfalcon tinymce](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle) bundle. For those who don't know it, this bundle package the use of *tinymce* to provide rich text editor. [*content_css*](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle#custom-css) configuration item allow to set the CSS that will be used to display the text in the rich editor.

My problem is that I don't know the name of the css because it's generated by assetic, and so cannot provide the correct *content_css* in *config.yml*. How can one handle this kind of situation? Is there a better way than getting a static css only for this bundle, with all the mess of keeping it current?

Comment: Symfony assetic can compile all the css into one css and you can give your desire name instead of using generated one with "output" parameter. Please check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: Good idea, I didn't know this option. I just don't really like having to set the name of the css in a twig template, and then use this same value in config.yml. But maybe I can set it in a parameter and use it at both location.